# Simultaneous diagonalization compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Searching in net, I found For an Hilbert space $H$, and an a commuting set $\cal F\subset Hom(H,H)$ of self-adjoint operators.  Then under suitable conditions, can be simultaneously (unitarily) diagonalized.(
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator_on_Hilbert_space#Simultaneous_diagonalisation )

After reading it, I thought about under which conditions is a family of compact positive or normal operators simultaneous diagonalization?

Would you please regard me to answer this question?

Answer (score 1):

For two operators: If selfadjoint operators $A$ and $B$ commute, then $B$ maps $\mathcal{N}(A-\lambda I)$ into itself because
$$
            (A-\lambda I)x = 0 \implies (A-\lambda I)Bx=B(A-\lambda I)x=0.
$$
For $\lambda\ne 0$, the restriction of $B$ to $\mathcal{N}(A-\lambda I)$ is selfadjoint and finite-dimensional; therefore, the restriction of $B$ has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. And these eigenvectors are also eigenvectors of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. The null space with $\lambda=0$ takes a little extra attention.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. my question is about noncommuting compact self-adjoint or positive operators $A,B$. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: @niki : Simultaneously diagonalizable operators commute for the same reason that diagonal matrices commute.